# Android POST to WCF Service crashes (org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject)

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, azure

I am trying to POST to a WCF Service but it crashes. Please help
I suspect it got something to do with the format of the POST params that was returned but do not know where is it exactly 
Here are my codes for the android application

Android Code :

```
public void onLoginBtnEvent(View v)
{
    //startActivity(new Intent("com.example.staffallocatorproject.LoggedIn"));
    new getLogin().execute(NRIC.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
}

private class getLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    String AccountID = "0";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URI + "/LoginMobile");
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        JSONStringer getCredential;
        try {
            getCredential = new JSONStringer()
                .object()
                    .key("LoginCredentials")
                        .object()                               
                            .key("NRIC").value(params[0])
                            .key("Password").value(params[1])
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject();

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getCredential.toString());

        request.setEntity(entity);

        // Send request to WCF service
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        reader.read(buffer);
        stream.close();

        JSONObject credentials = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));
        AccountID = credentials.getString("AccountID");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (AccountID != "0")
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoggedIn.class);
            i.putExtra("AccountID", AccountID);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid NRIC or Password" + ", AccountID:" + AccountID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Log cat:

```
>06-17 17:31:33.265: W/System.err(19753): org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
>06-17 17:31:33.265: W/System.err(19753):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>06-17 17:31:33.265: W/System.err(19753):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
>06-17 17:31:33.265: W/System.err(19753):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
>06-17 17:31:33.265: W/System.err(19753):   at com.example.staffallocatorproject.MainActivity$getLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:88)
>06-17 17:31:33.265: W/System.err(19753):   at com.example.staffallocatorproject.MainActivity$getLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>06-17 17:31:33.265: W/System.err(19753):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>06-17 17:31:33.273: W/System.err(19753):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>06-17 17:31:33.273: W/System.err(19753):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>06-17 17:31:33.273: W/System.err(19753):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>06-17 17:31:33.273: W/System.err(19753):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>06-17 17:31:33.273: W/System.err(19753):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>06-17 17:32:37.789: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.789: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.797: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.797: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.797: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.797: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.797: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.797: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.812: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.812: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.812: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.812: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.812: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.820: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.820: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.820: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.820: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.828: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.828: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.851: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.859: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.867: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.867: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.867: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.867: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>06-17 17:32:37.867: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19753): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

My WCF Service IService:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "LoginMobile",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    LoginCredentials GetLogin(LoginCredentials Lc);

[DataContract]
public class LoginCredentials
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AccountID")]
    public string AccountID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "NRIC")]
    public string NRIC
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

My Service.cs:

```
    public LoginCredentials GetLogin(LoginCredentials credentials)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PCSDB"].ConnectionString;
        string strCommandText = "Select AccountID from Account Where NRIC=@NRIC AND Password=@Password";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", credentials.NRIC);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", credentials.Password);

                int queryResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    credentials.AccountID = reader["AccountID"].ToString();
                    return credentials;
                }
                else
                {
                    credentials.AccountID = "0";
                    return credentials;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF service is passing back xml, which you are trying to parse as JSON. You need to configure your WCF binding to use JSON.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, but isnt my WCF already in JSON?

Comment: WCF allows you to configure many different types of communication mechanisms. One way to figure out how your WCF service is set up is to point a web browser to service address and appending ?singleWsdl to it, eg (http://localhost:8080/LoginMobile?singleWsdl). Look for the element <wsdl:binding> near the top. In there you should find information about the data format. If it has information about <soap>, then it is using xml.

Comment: The service binding is sometimes set up in the web.config file.

Comment: On the android side, you could also try logging the response string to see exactly what you are getting back.

Comment: my service says method not allowed, could you see it for me?
http://pcsstaffallocator.cloudapp.net/AllocationService.svc/LoginMobile?singleWsdl

Comment: how do i log the response string?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31875/discussion-between-john-atwood-and-bloopie-bloops)